# Disable separator for a single cell

Tags: ios, interface-builder

What I'd like to do is remove the separator for a single cell in a tableview. I'd like to keep the others ones as they are but I can't seem to find a way to do it.

I thought I could adjust the insets but from what I can see, these aren't the insets that I am trying to modify.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to get the same effect, but not answering exactly your question, is to disable `UITableView`'s separators and adding a 1px-height `UIView` to the prototype cells you want to have it.

Comment: I ended up doing it this way, it seems to work nicer across iOS versions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set cell separator inset in willDisplayCell.

```
if (indexPath.row == HideTheRowSeparator) {
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: That appears to push my cell content off to the right.

Comment: That doesn't happen to me though.